# How to open a details popup from a kendoui grid

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I'm trying to open a details popup to show more details about a record in a kendoUI grid.

I've seen this sample: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html

But instead of a grid, i'd like to open a popup passing the ID of the selected record.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the custom popup example?

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/custom-command.html

Answer (score 3):

The Kendo Grid has its own popup edit form that takes care of that and can also be customized with a template.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable.template

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward. Subscribe to the onChange event and alert the selected id. I assume you mean the attribute id. :

```
function onChange(arg) {
    var selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
                        return $(item).attr("id");
                    });

                   alert(selected);
                }

$(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: createRandomData(50),
                            pageSize: 5
                        },
                        change: onChange,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "FirstName",
                                title: "First Name"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "LastName",
                                title: "Last Name"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Age"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });​
```